# Unable to get error reasons in CUPS API while printing via USB

Tags: libusb, cups

I am using CUPS 1.6.3 for printing. The printer is connected via USB. The problem is while trying to print the job failed to print. I am able to see a reason for the failure 'Waiting for printer to become available' on CUPS interface. But I am not able to get the reason string through CUPS API. However when the printer is connected via network I am able to get the reason using  cupsGetOption("printer-state-reasons"...). Someone please help me to get the error reason while connecting via USB.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug your printer cable from your PC and plug it again on another USB port.